# merge html code with .csv file

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk

I have a spec file that looks like this `"PC DELL OptiPlex 3010MT i3 3220/2GB/500GB/DVD-RW/FREE DOS / 5Y NBD

Intel i3 3220 (Dual Core, 3.30GHz, 3MB, w/ HD2500 Graphics), 2GB (1x2GB) DDR3 PC3-1600MHz, 500GB HDD SATA III 7200rpm, DVD+/-RW (16x), FREE DOS, Warranty: 5Yr Basic Warranty NBD on site"`

So I need to populate an html table and then put it in a .csv file for uploading
So far I have managed to "clean" the file with the following script

```
 for f in $(ls *.csv)
 do
 #fix newline from file
 sed -i ':a;{N;s/NBD   \n/NBD,/};ba;s/"//g;' "$f" 

 #fix csv & and remove strings
 sed -i 's/"PC/PC/g;s/Core\,/Core/g;s/3\,/3./g;s/3MB\,//g;s/6MB\,//g;s/6MB//g;s/w   \///g;s/7,200/7200/g;s/site\"/site/g;s/3MB//g;s/3\,/3\./g;s/w\///g;s/3\,/3\./g;s/Cache\,)/Cache/g;s/ Internal Dell Business Audio Speaker\,//g;' "$f"

#don't know how to remove symbols with sed using awk
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} {for ( i in a) gsub(i,a[i])}1' template $f >temp.txt
mv temp.txt $f
done
```

And then using this script to populate the html table

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $(ls *.csv)
do
#split csv into 1line .csv files
split --additional-suffix=.csv -d -l 1 "$f" output/data_

#populate html file and create .html files
for file in $(ls output/*.csv)
do

IFS=","
while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10
do

echo "<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"100%\"> " 
echo "<tbody>"  
echo "<tr>  "   
echo "<td class=\"specsTitle\">Box</td> "
echo "<td class=\"specsDescript stripeBottom\">$f2</td> "
echo "</tr>     "   
echo "<tr>  "   
<snip>
done <$file  > output/temp.txt
mv output/temp.txt $file.html
done
done
#remove not important .csv
rm output/*.csv
```

So at this point I have several .html files in the output folder

The questions are:
1. How bad is the above code ? :-)
2. How do I put the code from the .html files in a .csv file that looks like this

```
 col1,col2,col3,HERE SHOULD BE THE HTML CODE FROM FILE1,col5,
 col1,col2,col3,HERE SHOULD BE THE HTML CODE FROM FILE2,col5,
```

I was thinking of using a template file and somehow add the several .html code. Any help?
Kind Regards

--EDIT-- 
THIS IS THE ORIGINAL INPUT
Original input:

```
 "PC DELL OptiPlex 3010MT i3 3220/2GB/500GB/DVD-RW/FREE DOS / 5Y NBD   
  Intel i3 3220 (Dual Core, 3.30GHz, 3MB, w/ HD2500 Graphics), 2GB (1x2GB) DDR3 PC3-1600MHz, 500GB HDD SATA III 7200rpm, DVD+/-RW (16x), FREE DOS, Warranty: 5Yr Basic Warranty NBD on site"
  "PC DELL OptiPlex 3010MT i5 3470/2GB/500GB/DVD-RW/FREE DOS / 5Y NBD   
   Intel i5 3470 (Quad Core, 3.20GHz Turbo,6MB, w/ HD2500 Graphics), 4GB (1x4GB)      DDR3, PC3-1600MHz, 750GB HDD SATA III 7200rpm, DVD+/-RW (16x), FREE DOS, Warranty: 5Yr   Basic Warranty NBD on site"
```

CSV template

```
  price,product code, SPECS,other things,
  300.00,CODE 2112334,    ,OTHER STRINGS,
  500.00,CODE 2222222,    ,OTHER STRINGS,
```

Desired .csv output:

```
  price,product code, SPECS,other things,
  300.00,CODE 2112334, <table style="width:300px"><tr><td>Proccessor</td><td>Intel i3 3220 (Dual Core, 3.30GHz</td></tr><tr><td>Memmory</td><td> 2GB (1x2GB) DDR3 PC3-1600MHz</td>tr><td>Hard Disk</td><td>500GB HDD SATA III 7200rpm</td></tr><tr><td>VGA</td><td>HD2500 Graphics</td></tr><tr><td>Warranty</td><td>5Yr Basic Warranty NBD on site</td></tr><tr><td>Ohter features</td><td>THIS IS NOT FROM THE SPECFILE</td></tr><tr><td>Ohter features 2</td><td>THIS IS ALSO NOT FROM THE SPECFILE</td></tr></tr></table>,OTHER STRINGS,
  500.00,CODE 2222222, <table style="width:300px"><tr><td>Proccessor</td><td>Intel i5 3470 (Quad Core 3.20GHz)</td></tr><tr><td>Memmory</td><td> 4GB (1x4GB) DDR3 PC3-1600MHz</td>tr><td>Hard Disk</td><td>750GB HDD SATA III 7200rpm</td></tr><tr><td>VGA</td><td>HD2500 Graphics</td></tr><tr><td>Warranty</td><td>5Yr Basic Warranty NBD on site</td></tr><tr><td>Ohter features</td><td>THIS IS NOT FROM THE SPECFILE</td></tr><tr><td>Ohter features 2</td><td>THIS IS ALSO NOT FROM THE SPECFILE</td></tr></tr></table>,OTHER STRINGS,
```

--EDIT--

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is [not a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). In your case, just do `for f in *.csv` instead. Also, can you post what your desired output would look like, based on the example input you gave?

Comment: Hi and hanks for the quick reply, the final .csv that I should use for uploading the file would be : col1,col2,col3,HERE SHOULD BE THE HTML CODE FROM FILE1,col5,
 col1,col2,col3,HERE SHOULD BE THE HTML CODE FROM FILE2,col5,   where col1 etc are predifined on a template.csv

Comment: This is the same information as in the post; what I was asking was for you to apply your desired processing to the example input you gave, and then post the final output (you can edit your post, it's better than adding it as a comment). In other words, give a complete example, start to finish, so that someone could write a (new) processing script based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that does not create any temporary files by using the `paste` utility to combine the lines of both the input file and the template file and processing the result in `awk`. I perform minimal clean up of the data with `sed`, just enough to make it work, but you can of course substitute in your full clean-up command.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Dummy header for the input file to match the header of the template file.
# Used only to make sure files have same number of lines.
heading="model,processor,speed,cache,graphics,memory,hd,optical,dos,warranty"

# Create input for awk that has the lines of input and template side by side.
paste -d ',' - template.csv <<< "$(echo $heading; sed -e 'N;s/ *\n/,/g' -e 's/"//g' input.csv)" | awk -F ',' '

  ## awk portion
  # First line: print just template.csv header (not dummy header).
  NR == 1 { for (i=11; i<NF; ++i) printf("%s,", $i); print(""); next }

  # Print each line, starting with the fields from template.csv,
  # then the HTML populated with values form input.csv,
  # and ending with the last fields form template.csv.
  { print($11","$12","" <table style=\"width:300px\"><tr><td>Processor</td><td>" $2 $3 ")</td></tr><tr><td>Memory</td><td>" $6 "</td></tr><tr><td>Hard Disk</td><td>" $7 "</td></tr><tr><td>VGA</td><td>" $5 "</td></tr><tr><td>Warranty</td><td>" $10 "</td></tr><tr><td>Other features</td><td>THIS IS NOT FROM THE SPECFILE</td></tr><tr><td>Other features 2</td><td>THIS IS ALSO NOT FROM THE SPECFILE</td></tr></table>," $14 ","); }'
```

This is already practically a one-liner:

```
paste -d ',' - template.csv <<< "$(echo "model,processor,speed,cache,graphics,memory,hd,optical,dos,warranty"; sed -e 'N;s/ *\n/,/g' -e 's/"//g' input.csv)" | awk -F ',' 'NR == 1 { for (i=11; i<NF; ++i) printf("%s,", $i); print(""); next } { print($11","$12","" <table style=\"width:300px\"><tr><td>Processor</td><td>" $2 $3 ")</td></tr><tr><td>Memory</td><td>" $6 "</td></tr><tr><td>Hard Disk</td><td>" $7 "</td></tr><tr><td>VGA</td><td>" $5 "</td></tr><tr><td>Warranty</td><td>" $10 "</td></tr><tr><td>Other features</td><td>THIS IS NOT FROM THE SPECFILE</td></tr><tr><td>Other features 2</td><td>THIS IS ALSO NOT FROM THE SPECFILE</td></tr></table>," $14 ","); }'
```

This solution assumes that you have combined the inputs into a single file, and cleaned it up to match the format given. Also, it assumes that the aggregate input file has the same number of data rows as the template file. You must also ensure that there are no extra/missing commas in the input file, since the comma is used as the field delimiter by this `awk` script.